# extracting folder and filename from dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filenames

How to extract folder\filename.txt from my dataframe

my dataframe:

```
C:\folder\one\file.txt
C:\folder\subfolder\two\file2.txt
```

I need on output last folder and filename:

```
df:
one\file.txt
two\file2.txt
```

my code:

```
df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: x.split('\\')[-1]) # i am receiving only file.txt - only filename , not last folder and filename
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly modify your call:

```py
import os
df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: os.sep.join(x.split('\\')[-2:])))
```

Here, `os.sep` is the system separator, which makes the call system independent. You could use any other string, too.

Comment: how to implement this code to cut filepath starting from specific folder?=`folder`
example, imput: `C:/fw/folder/folder1/file.txt` output : `folder/folder1/file.txt` maybe using `find()` function?

Comment: There a tons of methods to do this. Depends a bit on your use case. Generally, I would suggest using OS independent code as much as possible, e.g. incorporating the os.path submodule.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
# This function takes in input a list and converts it into a dir chain string
def convert(string_list): 

    string = "" 

    # traversing each element of the list and using it to create a new string  
    for x in string_list: 
        string += x + "\\"

    # returning string[:-1] to get rid of the redundant \ in the end of the string (not advised when location is of a directory)
    return string[:-1] 


a = r"C:\folder\one\file.txt"

print(convert(a.split("\\")[-2:]))
```

output:

```
one\file.txt
```